# Magento2 Contact Form Emails Not Received

Tags: magento2, contact-form

We're experiencing an issue with one of our Magento 2 sites where the contact form emails are not being received.

Order emails are being received - it's only the contact form that is failing.

There is nothing in the exception log, the server says they've been sent, there are no errors I can find at any level... but it's only the Contact form emails that don't work.

It does work on our development server - it's only the live one that is experiencing issues.

Does anyone know if the contact form emails work differently from order emails in some subtle way that might mean it doesn't work?

I'm out of ideas on how to debug this further, and I can't really understand why one set of emails (order/customer emails) would work while another set (contact form) don't. There must be some difference, but I haven't found it.

Magento 2.2.2 Open Source

Comment: Did you checked in spam folder ?

Comment: Yes. The server reports sending them. They are not received.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It's 2020 now and we're still experiencing this issue an a 2.3.5p1 build

Comment: Honestly, we must have figured it out, but I have no idea now how.